# Convolution: the last element in the convolution is never right

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ implementation of convolution with the following function

```
vector<double> Conv(vector<double> a, vector<double> b)
{
    // a and b are the same size
    int n = a.size() * 2 - 1;
    vector<double> c;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c.push_back(0);
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            c[i] += a[j] * b[i - j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

The problem is that all the convolution values are correct except for the last one. I checked using a convolution calculator I found online.

Example input:

> Vector a = <0.961232, 0.00685581, 0.905588, 0.914544>
>
> Vector b = <0.719889, 0.675933, 0.0571511, 0.148412>
>
> Returned vector =  <0.691981, 0.654664, 0.711493, 1.41354, 0.670944, 0.186668, 0.653971>
>
> Expected = <0.691980343248, 0.65466385166109, 0.71149237410793, 1.413537159886891, 0.67094330437252, 0.1866673218544, 0.135729304128>

The accuracy of the floats in the returned vector is fine, but the last result doesn't match up.

Comment: Could you give a sample output and the expected output?

Comment: Does this code actually work?  You're accessing outside the bounds of the `a` and `b` vectors.

Comment: It seems to work well aside from the last value.

Comment: What will happen with j is 4? In programming  that's called out of bound.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments of other community members, I believe that your algorithm is not quite correct. Instead of debugging, I decided to find a correct one by google.

These two links gave me the clue:

- [Convolution of Vectors (Mlmode)](http://www.omatrix.com/manual/mlmode_conv.htm)
- [Convolution of two vectors in R](https://portfolium.com/entry/convolution-of-two-vectors-in-r)

I used these links to make a small sample in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename VALUE>
void convolve(
  std::vector<VALUE> &c, // out
  const std::vector<VALUE> &a, const std::vector<VALUE> &b) // in
{
  const size_t nA = a.size(), nB = b.size();
  const size_t nC = nA + nB - 1;
  c.clear(); c.resize(nC, (VALUE)0);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nA; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < nB; ++j) {
      c[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
    }
  }
}

template <typename VALUE>
inline std::vector<VALUE> convolve(
  const std::vector<VALUE> &a, const std::vector<VALUE> &b)
{
  std::vector<VALUE> c; convolve(c, a, b); return c;
}

template <typename VALUE>
void print(
  std::ostream &out, const char *label, const std::vector<VALUE> &vec)
{
  out << label << '[' << vec.size() << "]: {";
  const char *sep = " ";
  for (const VALUE &v : vec) {
    out << sep << v;
    sep = ", ";
  }
  out << " }" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  // test 1
  // http://www.omatrix.com/manual/mlmode_conv.htm
  { std::cout << "Test 1:" << std::endl;
    const std::vector<int> a = {
      1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    };
    std::vector<int> c;
    convolve(c, a, a);
    print(std::cout, "a", a);
    std::cout << "Convolution of a and a:" << std::endl;
    print(std::cout, "c", c);
  }
  // test 2
  { std::cout << "Test 2:" << std::endl;
    const std::vector<float> a = {
      0.961232f, 0.00685581f, 0.905588f, 0.914544f
    };
    const std::vector<float> b = {
      0.719889f, 0.675933f, 0.0571511f, 0.148412f
    };
    std::vector<float> c;
    convolve(c, a, b);
    print(std::cout, "a", a);
    print(std::cout, "b", b);
    std::cout << "Convolution of a and b:" << std::endl;
    print(std::cout, "c", c);
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Notes:

1. To copy a vector (as it is done in `return`) might be expensive for large vectors. Therefore, I provide the result vector by reference. (For those, who prefer `return` I wrote an `inline` wrapper but I didn't use it.)
2. Instead of `vector::push_back()`, I used `vector::resize()`. It is usually less expensive to do allocation at once (especially if size is known from beginning). The `vector::resize()` is also used for initialization. To discard possible previous values, a `vector::clear()` is done before. (`vector::clear()` is a cheap method because it does not free storage but simply resets internal number of elements.)
3. I made `convolve` a template. This makes the usage more flexible.

I compiled and tested it with g++ in cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o vector-convolution vector-convolution.cc 

$ ./vector-convolution.exe 
Test 1:
a[5]: { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
Convolution of a and a:
c[9]: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }
Test 2:
a[4]: { 0.961232, 0.00685581, 0.905588, 0.914544 }
b[4]: { 0.719889, 0.675933, 0.0571511, 0.148412 }
Convolution of a and b:
c[7]: { 0.69198, 0.654664, 0.711492, 1.41354, 0.670943, 0.186667, 0.135729 }

$
```

This looks quite good:

- Test 1 matches the expected values according to [Convolution of Vectors (Mlmode)](http://www.omatrix.com/manual/mlmode_conv.htm).
- Test 2 matches the expected values of your question.